# Using Linq and C#, is it possible to join two lists but with interleaving at each item?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Having two lists of same object type. I want to join them using an interleave pattern where **i** items of the first list are separated by **j** items from the second list.

In essence:

First list

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}

Second list

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

where the grouping count for the first list is 3 and for the second list is 2.

resulting in

> {a, b, c, 0, 1, e, f, g, 2, 3, h, 4}

Is this possible with Linq?

Comment: In addition to Marc's suggestion, here's a link showing how to implement a zip extension method: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx

Comment: I'm not convinced that Zip would work here... possibly Zip combined with a partitioning operator...

Comment: `Zip` would work if you apply `SelectMany` to result of the `Zip` to expand each tuple into a sequence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing within LINQ itself to do this - it seems a pretty specialized requirement - but it's fairly easy to implement:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InterleaveWith<T>
   (this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second,
    int firstGrouping, int secondGrouping)
{
    using (IEnumerator<T> firstIterator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<T> secondIterator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool exhaustedFirst = false;
        // Keep going while we've got elements in the first sequence.
        while (!exhaustedFirst)
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < firstGrouping; i++)
            {
                 if (!firstIterator.MoveNext())
                 {
                     exhaustedFirst = true;
                     break;
                 }
                 yield return firstIterator.Current;
            }
            // This may not yield any results - the first sequence
            // could go on for much longer than the second. It does no
            // harm though; we can keep calling MoveNext() as often
            // as we want.
            for (int i = 0; i < secondGrouping; i++)
            {
                 // This is a bit ugly, but it works...
                 if (!secondIterator.MoveNext())
                 {
                     break;
                 }
                 yield return secondIterator.Current;
            }
        }
        // We may have elements in the second sequence left over.
        // Yield them all now.
        while (secondIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return secondIterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stecy: There was a bug in the first version. Try this one.

Comment: You still need to work on that; firstGrouping and secondGrouping are  integers, not iterators as you use them in the for loops. But it's the best approach to the problem, hands down.

Comment: @Randolpho: Fixed (it was just the once.)

Comment: Just checked, and it compiles now. I really should try to get into the habit of compiling *before* posting...

Comment: Compiles fine but does not give the expected result. Seems to skip one element from the first list upon returning to the top of the while loop...

Comment: @Stecy: I'll edit my answer to match, to avoid the bug propagating.

Comment: @Jon - you are right - my comment was incorrect. The danger of "one quick glance before I leg it" style comments. I must avoid that!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: LINQPad is your friend for compile-before-post coding. Much faster than firing up VS and loading a scratch project.

Comment: @Randolpho: Oh I certainly wouldn't fire up VS for anything so trivial - but I do have a lightweight text editor I tend to use. Must try LINQPad for this though. I've been considering an "SO-specific" editor with built-in useful things like finding MSDN links.

Comment: @Jon: Removed my comment about the correction since you've updated your answer.