# Mix Items to new List with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say this is my list {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }

Now I would like to mix the items to following list: { 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, ..}

Basically always one item from left side and one item from right side of the list.

Is there a possibilities to create this just by using linq statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
var sample = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var res = sample
    .Select((z, i) => i % 2 == 0 
        ? sample[i / 2] 
        : sample[sample.Count - i / 2 - 1])
    .ToList();
```

Basically it uses a modulo to either select an item at the start of the list or at the end.

Do note I didn't even used the enumerated `z` value, so while LINQ is actually used here, it's not anything else than a simple `for` loop.

EDIT:

If you want something that computes faster, try something without LINQ:

```
int count = sample.Count;
var res = new List<int>(count);

for (int i = 0; i < sample.Count; i++)
{
    var iDividedByRwo = i / 2;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        res.Add(sample[iDividedByRwo]);
    }
    else
    {
        res.Add(sample[count - iDividedByRwo - 1]);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: okay, I'm doing your job but...

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sample = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).ToList();

    var z1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Test1(sample);
    }

    z1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(z1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    var z2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Test2(sample);
    }

    z2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(z2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.Read();
}

private static void Test1(IList<int> input)
{
    var res2 = input
        .Select((z, i) => i % 2 == 0
            ? input[i / 2]
            : input[input.Count - i / 2 - 1])
        .ToList();
}

private static void Test2(IList<int> input)
{
    int count = input.Count;
    var res = new List<int>(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        var iDividedByRwo = i / 2;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            res.Add(input[iDividedByRwo]);
        }
        else
        {
            res.Add(input[count - iDividedByRwo - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
4195
1136
```

Insert other methods and compare results if you want to get the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* do this using just LINQ (reasonably briefly, even), but it's not exactly pleasant:

- Reverse the list
- Zip it with the original list to get pairs (1, 9), (2, 8) etc
- Flatten the result
- Take only the original number

So:

```
var query = original.Zip(original.Reverse(), (x, y) => new[] { x, y })
                    .SelectMany(x => x)
                    .Take(original.Count());
```

If I were actually going to use this code, I'd definitely put a comment in there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758451/3629689 ;)

Comment: @jeffdot: Yes, with `Interleave` you could just use `original.Interleave(original.Reverse()).Take(original.Count())`

Comment: Thanks Jon can you take a look at ken2k answer and tell me which might perform better please?

Comment: @devhedgehog: If you really care about performance, there are quicker solutions than either of these. But you didn't ask about performance. Do you have any evidence that either of these doesn't perform *well enough* for your purposes?

Comment: I would like to pick the fastest one since I am handling 100k items. What would be the quickest solution please?

Comment: Why don't you try them both? And next time, please state requirements in your question, rather than inviting people to answer with insufficient information. To state again: I wouldn't use *either* of these solutions if performance is critical. (And do you mean that a single list has 100K items? Or that you're handling 100K lists?)

Comment: Sorry for lacking info in question. If there is a faster solution than this two I would take it. Can you post it please. I have actually a tree which I flatten to a single list therefore list can become super huge for example 2000 tree nodes and each has 100 items that would result in 2000 times 100.

Comment: @devhedgehog See my edit. Just build a quick benchmark and test all methods by yourself.

Comment: @devhedgehog: Again, do you have evidence that it's not fast enough anyway? Usually you don't want the *fastest possible* solution... you want the simplest solution which is fast *enough*. Have you defined your performance criteria yet? (ken2k's approach seems about right to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
var list = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
List<int> alternatingOrder = list
        .Select((i, index) => new
        {
            i,
            Margin = index < list.Count / 2 ? index : list.Count - ++index
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Margin)
        .Select(x => x.i)
        .ToList();
```