# Merge 2 lists by alternating elements

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
item1
item2
item3
.
.
itemX
```

and

```
item11
item22
item33
.
.
itemXX
```

I would like to merge those 2 lists into one by alternating the list elements so the resulting list will be like this:

```
item1
item11
item2
item22
.
.
itemX
itemXX
```

What is the best approach to do this in python?

What I am really trying to accomplish is to build a html table with X-rows and 2 columns so I need alternating lines with elements from both lists so that elements from list1 will go to column 1 and same for list2.

Comment: Best thing to do: code it. Come back if you have a specific question related to [mcve] that is a problem - currently you are just asking _us_ to code for you .

Comment: Dupe: [pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)

Comment: and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleave-multiple-lists-of-the-same-length-in-python

Comment: and here [using-linq-and-c-is-it-possible-to-join-two-lists-but-with-interleaving-at-each-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758404/using-linq-and-c-is-it-possible-to-join-two-lists-but-with-interleaving-at-each-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
foo=[1,3,5,7,9]
bar=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
new_list=[]
for f,b in itertools.zip_longest(foo,bar):
    if f:
        new_list.append(f)
    if b:
        new_list.append(b)
print(new_list)
```